# does not contain public defination GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with a MVC Web Application I'm building in C#.The error is stating

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'Ayakkabı.Models.Resimler' because 'Ayakkabı.Models.Resimler' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'".

[image]

Comment: change model to `List<Ayakkabı.Models.Resimler>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your Resimler type to List<> inside Ayakkabı.Models.Urunler or you can use  for loop https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx